# Create IDs for each <li> (including nestings) in a jQuery sortable list

Tags: jquery, html, nested, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list with nested `LI` items. I'm looking for create an `ID` for each `LI` in the group.

Example. If I have this:

```
<li class="main"> Cat 0
    <ul class="subCat">
        <li>Subcat 0
            <ul class="subCat">
                <li>Sub-Subcat 0
                    <ul class="subCat"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Subcat 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Ok, those `ul.subCat` are there to nest other `li` items. I want to make a function to add `ID`s to `li` elements and its `li` child elements. This function will be called by every order change.

The result should be something like this:

```
<li class="main" id="cat_0"> Cat 0
    <ul class="subCat">
        <li id="cat_0_0">Subcat 0
            <ul class="subCat">
                <li id="cat_0_0_0">Sub-Subcat 0
                    <ul class="subCat"></ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="cat_0_1">Subcat 1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And, for each `li.main` element repeat the story to reach 4 levels (0 to 3).

My actual code is this one:

```
// level 0
target = $('#ulMenu >li');
for( i=0; i<=target.length-1; i++ ){
    target.eq(i).attr('id', 'cat_' + i).addClass('main');
}

// level 1
//------------------------------------------------------------------
$('#ulMenu >li.main').each(function(){

    target = $(this).children('ul').children('li');
    for( i=0; i<=target.length-1; i++ ){
        father = target.eq(i).parent('ul').parent('li').attr('id').split('_')[1];
        target.eq(i).attr('id', 'cat_' + padre + '_' + i);
    }
```

I have to know how to add `ID`s to the rest of elements. I was trying but I can't found with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution that'll work to any depth you want:

```
function menuID(el, base) {
    base = base || 'cat';
    $(el).filter('li').each(function(i) {
        this.id = base + '_' + i;
        menuID($(this).children('ul').children('li'), this.id);
    });
};

menuID('.main');​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/XhnYa/

Alternatively, here's a version as a jQuery plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.menuID = function(base) {
        base = base || 'cat';
        this.filter('li').each(function(i) {
            this.id = base + '_' + i;
            $(this).children('ul').children('li').menuID(this.id);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.main').menuID();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/5hkQU/

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried both examples (thx @trapper and @Alnitak) and works fine.

I will read about recursion. Thank you again. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it...

```
$('#ulMenu').children('li').each(function(cat) {

    $(this).attr('id', 'cat_' + cat).children('ul').children('li').each(function(sCat) {

        $(this).attr('id', 'cat_' + cat + '_' + sCat).children('ul').children('li').each(function(ssCat) {

            $(this).attr('id', 'cat_' + cat + '_' + sCat + '_' + ssCat);
        });
    });
});​
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6YR5p/2/

Comment: You could do with learning about recursion.  Then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727064/create-ids-for-each-li-including-nestings-in-a-jquery-sortable-list#comment17190054_12727370

Comment: that's a joke on recursion...   :whoosh: